# Sitecore Docker exited with code 1 while setting Sitecore admin password

Tags: docker, container

While running up.ps1 in step 7 of Create the ScNext(MyProject name locally) solution in [Walkthrough: Setting up a development environment with the Sitecore Containers template for Next.js](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html), container mssql-init-1 exciting repeatedly.[image: mssql-init-1 excited (1)]

This is error log of mssql-init-1 container:

```
2023-03-06 23:47:06 Start publishing dacpacs
2023-03-06 23:47:06 Configuration option 'contained database authentication' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
2023-03-06 23:47:06 Starting to deploy 'Sitecore.Core' dacpac ...
2023-03-06 23:47:13 Publishing to database 'Sitecore.Core' on server 'mssql'.
2023-03-06 23:47:18 Initializing deployment (Start)
2023-03-06 23:48:20 Initializing deployment (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:48:20 Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
2023-03-06 23:48:20 Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:48:20 Updating database (Start)
2023-03-06 23:48:22 Creating Sitecore.Core...
2023-03-06 23:48:23 An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
2023-03-06 23:48:23 *** Could not deploy package.
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file "C:\data\Sitecore.Core_Primary.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:48:23 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:48:23     ON 
2023-03-06 23:48:23     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:48:23     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:48:23 
2023-03-06 23:48:23 
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:48:23 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:48:23     ON 
2023-03-06 23:48:23     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:48:23     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:48:23 
2023-03-06 23:48:23 
2023-03-06 23:48:23 
2023-03-06 23:48:24 Get-ChildItem : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying 
2023-03-06 23:48:24 C:\resources\Sitecore.Core.dacpac
2023-03-06 23:48:24 At C:\DeployDatabases.ps1:133 char:5
2023-03-06 23:48:24 +     Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter *.dacpac | ForEach-Object {
2023-03-06 23:48:24 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-03-06 23:48:24     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlpackage exit...ore.Core.da 
2023-03-06 23:48:24    cpac:String) [Get-ChildItem], RuntimeException
2023-03-06 23:48:24     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying C: 
2023-03-06 23:48:24    \resources\Sitecore.Core.dacpac,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItem  
2023-03-06 23:48:24   Command
2023-03-06 23:48:24  
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Updating database (Failed)
2023-03-06 23:48:23 Time elapsed 00:01:10.83
2023-03-06 23:48:24 Starting to deploy 'Sitecore.Processing.pools' dacpac ...
2023-03-06 23:48:29 Publishing to database 'Sitecore.Processing.pools' on server 'mssql'.
2023-03-06 23:48:35 Initializing deployment (Start)
2023-03-06 23:49:35 Initializing deployment (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:49:35 Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
2023-03-06 23:49:35 Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:49:35 Updating database (Start)
2023-03-06 23:49:37 Creating Sitecore.Processing.pools...
2023-03-06 23:49:38 An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Updating database (Failed)
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Time elapsed 00:01:11.00
2023-03-06 23:49:38 *** Could not deploy package.
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file "C:\data\Sitecore.Processing.pools_Primary.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:49:38 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:49:38     ON 
2023-03-06 23:49:38     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:49:38     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:49:38 
2023-03-06 23:49:38 
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
2023-03-06 23:49:38 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:49:38 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:49:38     ON 
2023-03-06 23:49:38     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:49:38     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:49:38 
2023-03-06 23:49:38 
2023-03-06 23:49:38 
2023-03-06 23:49:39 Get-ChildItem : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying 
2023-03-06 23:49:39 C:\resources\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Processing.pools.dacpac
2023-03-06 23:49:39 At C:\DeployDatabases.ps1:133 char:5
2023-03-06 23:49:39 +     Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter *.dacpac | ForEach-Object {
2023-03-06 23:49:39 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-03-06 23:49:39     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlpackage exit...ng.pools.da 
2023-03-06 23:49:39    cpac:String) [Get-ChildItem], RuntimeException
2023-03-06 23:49:39     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying C: 
2023-03-06 23:49:39    \resources\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Processing.pools.dacpac,Microsoft  
2023-03-06 23:49:39   .PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
2023-03-06 23:49:39  
2023-03-06 23:50:06 *** Could not deploy package.
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file "C:\data\Sitecore.core_Primary.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:50:06 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:50:06     ON 
2023-03-06 23:50:06     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:49:39 Starting to deploy 'Sitecore.core' dacpac ...
2023-03-06 23:49:44 Publishing to database 'Sitecore.core' on server 'mssql'.
2023-03-06 23:49:47 Initializing deployment (Start)
2023-03-06 23:50:04 Initializing deployment (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:50:04 Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
2023-03-06 23:50:04 Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
2023-03-06 23:50:04 Updating database (Start)
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Creating Sitecore.core...
2023-03-06 23:50:06 An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Updating database (Failed)
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Time elapsed 00:00:24.13
2023-03-06 23:50:06     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:50:06 
2023-03-06 23:50:06 
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
2023-03-06 23:50:06 Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2023-03-06 23:50:06 CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
2023-03-06 23:50:06     ON 
2023-03-06 23:50:06     PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
2023-03-06 23:50:06     LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
2023-03-06 23:50:06 
2023-03-06 23:50:09 Sql Sharding deployment tool executing...
2023-03-06 23:50:15 *** Welcome to Sitecore xDB Collection SQL Sharding Deployment Tool ***
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Tool was run with the following configuration:
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Operation: create
2023-03-06 23:50:15 SQL server connection:
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Server name: mssql
2023-03-06 23:50:15 User: sa
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Integrated security: False
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Connection Timeout: 15
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Database edition: Basic
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Elastic Pool: 
2023-03-06 23:50:15 Shard map manager database name: Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Shard map names: ContactIdShardMap, DeviceProfileIdShardMap, ContactIdentifiersIndexShardMap
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Shard number: 2
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Shard name prefix: Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Shard
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Shard name suffix: 
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Dacpac file path: C:\\resources\\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac
2023-03-06 23:50:16 Force operation: False
2023-03-06 23:50:18 Shard Map Manager has not yet been created
2023-03-06 23:50:18 Creating database Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager
2023-03-06 23:50:19 The file "C:\data\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
2023-03-06 23:50:06 
2023-03-06 23:50:06 
2023-03-06 23:50:07 Get-ChildItem : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying 
2023-03-06 23:50:07 C:\resources\jss\Sitecore.core.dacpac
2023-03-06 23:50:07 At C:\DeployDatabases.ps1:133 char:5
2023-03-06 23:50:07 +     Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter *.dacpac | ForEach-Object {
2023-03-06 23:50:07 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-03-06 23:50:07     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlpackage exit...ore.core.da 
2023-03-06 23:50:07    cpac:String) [Get-ChildItem], RuntimeException
2023-03-06 23:50:07     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlpackage exited with code 1 while deploying C: 
2023-03-06 23:50:07    \resources\jss\Sitecore.core.dacpac,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChild  
2023-03-06 23:50:07   ItemCommand
2023-03-06 23:50:07  
2023-03-06 23:50:24 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
2023-03-06 23:50:19 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The file "C:\data\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
2023-03-06 23:50:19 CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.EntLib.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Framework.TransientFaultHandling.Sql.SqlRetryHelper.Execute[T](IDbConnection connection, Func`1 sqlWork, Func`2 commandRetryPolicy)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.SqlDatabaseManager.CreateDatabase(String serverName, String databaseName)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.Operations.CreateShardClusterOperation.CreateShardMapManagerAndShard(IShardDeploymentManager shardDeploymentManager, IShardClusterManager shardManager, ISqlDatabaseManager sqlDatabaseManager, IDacpacManager dacpacManager, IRangeManager rangeManager, IConfiguration configuration)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.Operations.CreateShardClusterOperation.Execute(IManagersFactory managers)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.OperationContext.Execute(String operationKey, IManagersFactory factory)
2023-03-06 23:50:19    at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.Program.ExecuteApplication()
2023-03-06 23:50:19 ClientConnectionId:dea7c591-0b54-47a9-8b7e-d85f85b8e539
2023-03-06 23:50:19 Error Number:5118,State:1,Class:16
2023-03-06 23:50:24 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot open database "Sitecore.Core" requested by the login. The login failed..
2023-03-06 23:50:24 sqlcmd exited with code 1 while setting Sitecore admin password
2023-03-06 23:50:24 At C:\SetSitecoreAdminPassword.ps1:29 char:5
2023-03-06 23:50:24 +     throw "sqlcmd exited with code $LASTEXITCODE while setting Siteco ...
2023-03-06 23:50:24 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-03-06 23:50:24     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlcmd exited w... admin pass 
2023-03-06 23:50:24    word:String) [], RuntimeException
2023-03-06 23:50:24     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlcmd exited with code 1 while setting Sitecore 
2023-03-06 23:50:24     admin password
2023-03-06 23:50:24
```

Steps I have tried so far

1. I have changed the Docker Engine setting to

> {
> "builder": {
> "gc": {
> "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
> "enabled": true
> }
> },
> "dns": [
> "8.8.8.8",
> "1.1.1.1"
> ],
> "experimental": false,
> "features": {
> "buildkit": true
> }
> }
> 2) Cleaned all the docker containers, Pruned it, Restarted machine, Restarted Docker engine multiple times
> 3) Tried in different network(office, home, with zscaler, w/o Zscaler)

I am getting the same "login failed" message for the same SQL server init container.

Please share the solution? Thank for your support!

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with login. It looks like there is an issue creating the LDF/MDF files when creating the databases in first place. Im assuming you are mounting a volume to your local drive? If so, please confirm that the user running the setup has permissions for that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key is the error line:

> 2023-03-06 23:48:23 Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg
> 5118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file
> "C:\data\Sitecore.Core_Primary.mdf" **is compressed but does not reside**
> **in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed**.

Check that you have not mounted your SQL volume (containing your DB files) to a drive which has compression enabled. Right click your drive, and look for this checkbox:
[image]

As stated on the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/support-databases-compressed-volumes), SQL Server DBs are not supported on compressed drives.